# Plot 3D data in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have a 3D dataset:

```
data = data.frame(
    x = rep( c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5), each=5),
    y = rep( c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 5)
)

data$z = runif(
    25,
    min = (data$x*data$y - 0.1 * (data$x*data$y)),
    max = (data$x*data$y + 0.1 * (data$x*data$y))
)

data
str(data)
```

And I want to plot it, but the built-in-functions of R alwyas give the error

> increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected

```
# ### 3D Plots ######################################################
# built-in function always give the error
#    "increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected"
demo(image)
image(x = data$x, y = data$y, z = data$z)

demo(persp)
persp(data$x,data$y,data$z)

contour(data$x,data$y,data$z)
```

When I searched on the internet, I found that this message happens when combinations of X and Y values are not unique. But here they are unique.

I tried some other libraries and there it works without problems. But I don't like the default style of the plots (the built-in functions should fulfill my expectations).

```
# ### 3D Scatterplot ######################################################
# Nice plots without surface maps?
install.packages("scatterplot3d", dependencies = TRUE)
library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(x = data$x, y = data$y, z = data$z)

# ### 3D Scatterplot ######################################################
# Only to play around?
install.packages("rgl", dependencies = TRUE)
library(rgl)
plot3d(x = data$x, y = data$y, z = data$z)
lines3d(x = data$x, y = data$y, z = data$z)
surface3d(x = data$x, y = data$y, z = data$z)
```

Why are my datasets not accepted by the built-in functions?

Comment: image(data$x, data$y, matrix(data$z, 5, 5))

Comment: I modified the command a bit, to make it more general, and i added the "unique"-function, since in the original dataset there are several copies of one and the same x and y-values: `image(
 unique(data$x),
 unique(data$y),
 matrix(
  data$z,
  length(unique(data$x)),
  length(unique(data$y))
 )
)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're working with "real" data for which the grid intervals and sequence cannot be guaranteed to be increasing or unique (hopefully the `(x,y,z)` combinations are unique at least, even if these triples are duplicated), I would recommend the `akima` package for interpolating from an irregular grid to a regular one.

Using your definition of `data`:

```
library(akima)
im <- with(data,interp(x,y,z))
with(im,image(x,y,z))
```

[image]

And this should work not only with `image` but similar functions as well.

Note that the default grid to which your data is mapped to by `akima::interp` is defined by 40 equal intervals spanning the range of `x` and `y` values:

```
> formals(akima::interp)[c("xo","yo")]
$xo
seq(min(x), max(x), length = 40)

$yo
seq(min(y), max(y), length = 40)
```

But of course, this can be overridden by passing arguments `xo` and `yo` to `akima::interp`.

Answer (score 66):

I use the `lattice` package for almost everything I plot in R and it has a corresponing plot to `persp` called `wireframe`. Let `data` be the way Sven defined it.

```
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data=data)
```

[image: wireframe plot]

Or how about this (modification of fig 6.3 in [Deepanyan Sarkar's book](http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html)):

```
p <- wireframe(z ~ x * y, data=data)
npanel <- c(4, 2)
rotx <- c(-50, -80)
rotz <- seq(30, 300, length = npanel[1]+1)
update(p[rep(1, prod(npanel))], layout = npanel,
    panel = function(..., screen) {
        panel.wireframe(..., screen = list(z = rotz[current.column()],
                                           x = rotx[current.row()]))
    })
```

[image: Multiple wireframe plots using panel and update]

### Update: Plotting surfaces with OpenGL

Since this post continues to draw attention I want to add the OpenGL way to make 3-d plots too (as suggested by @tucson below). First we need to reformat the dataset from xyz-tripplets to axis vectors `x` and `y` and a matrix `z`.

```
x <- 1:5/10
y <- 1:5
z <- x %o% y
z <- z + .2*z*runif(25) - .1*z

library(rgl)
persp3d(x, y, z, col="skyblue")
```

[image: rgl::persp3d]

This image can be freely rotated and scaled using the mouse, or modified with additional commands, and when you are happy with it you save it using `rgl.snapshot`.

```
rgl.snapshot("myplot.png")
```

Answer (score 31):

Adding to the solutions of others, I'd like to suggest using the [`plotly`](https://plot.ly/r/) package for `R`, as this has worked well for me.

Below, I'm using the reformatted dataset suggested above, from xyz-tripplets to axis vectors x and y and a matrix z:

```
x <- 1:5/10
y <- 1:5
z <- x %o% y
z <- z + .2*z*runif(25) - .1*z

library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=x,y=y,z=z, type="surface")
```

[image]

The rendered surface can be rotated and scaled using the mouse. This works fairly well in RStudio.

You can also try it with the built-in `volcano` dataset from `R`:

```
plot_ly(z=volcano, type="surface")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried to copy/paste your code, but at the end nothing happened. How to visualize it?

Comment: @ilFonta if you're using RStudio the graph should appear in the viewer pane and not the plot pane.

Answer (score 10):

I think the following code is close to what you want

```
x    <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
y    <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
zfun <- function(a,b) {a*b * ( 0.9 + 0.2*runif(a*b) )}
z    <- outer(x, y, FUN="zfun")
```

It gives data like this (note that `x` and `y` are both increasing)

```
> x
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
> y
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> z
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.1037159 0.2123455 0.3244514 0.4106079 0.4777380
[2,] 0.2144338 0.4109414 0.5586709 0.7623481 0.9683732
[3,] 0.3138063 0.6015035 0.8308649 1.2713930 1.5498939
[4,] 0.4023375 0.8500672 1.3052275 1.4541517 1.9398106
[5,] 0.5146506 1.0295172 1.5257186 2.1753611 2.5046223
```

and a graph like

```
persp(x, y, z)
```

[image: persp(x, y, z)]

Comment: Thaks for the answer. The problem is that I work with real data. There you nerver know the function that created you data. I used the function only for creating an artificial datset.

Comment: I think the question is whether you can rearrange your real data so `z` is a matrix and `x` and `y` vectors.

Comment: To use `persp` and `image` in this way define `z` as an `n` by `m` matrix where `n`,`m` is the lengths of `x`,`y` (defined as Henry did).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why the code above did not work for the library `rgl`, but the following link has a great example with the same library.
Run the code in R and you will obtain a **beautiful 3d plot that you can turn around in all angles**.

http://statisticsr.blogspot.de/2008/10/some-r-functions.html

```
########################################################################
## another example of 3d plot from my personal reserach, use rgl library
########################################################################
# 3D visualization device system

library(rgl);
data(volcano)
dim(volcano)

peak.height <- volcano;
ppm.index <- (1:nrow(volcano));
sample.index <- (1:ncol(volcano));

zlim <- range(peak.height)
zlen <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1
colorlut <- terrain.colors(zlen) # height color lookup table
col <- colorlut[(peak.height-zlim[1]+1)] # assign colors to heights for each point
open3d()

ppm.index1 <- ppm.index*zlim[2]/max(ppm.index);
sample.index1 <- sample.index*zlim[2]/max(sample.index)

title.name <- paste("plot3d ", "volcano", sep = "");
surface3d(ppm.index1, sample.index1, peak.height, color=col, back="lines", main = title.name);
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"), n =20)

sample.name <- paste("col.", 1:ncol(volcano), sep="");
sample.label <- as.integer(seq(1, length(sample.name), length = 5));

axis3d('y+',at = sample.index1[sample.label], sample.name[sample.label], cex = 0.3);
axis3d('y',at = sample.index1[sample.label], sample.name[sample.label], cex = 0.3)
axis3d('z',pos=c(0, 0, NA))

ppm.label <- as.integer(seq(1, length(ppm.index), length = 10));
axes3d('x', at=c(ppm.index1[ppm.label], 0, 0), abs(round(ppm.index[ppm.label], 2)), cex = 0.3);

title3d(main = title.name, sub = "test", xlab = "ppm", ylab = "samples", zlab = "peak")
rgl.bringtotop();
```