# How to plot 3D scatter diagram using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, plotly, scatter3d

I tried to use the [plotly](https://plotly-r.com/) package, but it is not working in my case at all. The [ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) package is working for 2D plots but it is giving an error when adding one more axis. How to solve this issue?

```r
ggplot(data,aes(x=D1,y=D2,z=D3,color=Sample)) +
  geom_point()
```

How to add one more axis and get the 3D plot in this?

Comment: Show me your data. I was always using `plot3d()` to get 3D plots such like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdMN3.png

Comment: I don't think ggplot2 handles pseudo-3d graphics. If you believe differently, then please provide more detail about why you think it should be possible.  ... And as always, you _should_ be providing a data example.

Answer (score 77):

Since you tagged your question with `plotly` and said that you've tried to use it with plotly, I think it would be helpful to give you a working code solution in `plotly`:

Creating some data to plot with:

```
set.seed(417)
library(plotly)
temp <- rnorm(100, mean=30, sd=5)
pressure <- rnorm(100)
dtime <- 1:100
```

Graphing your 3d scatterplot using plotly's `scatter3d` type:

```
plot_ly(x=temp, y=pressure, z=dtime, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", color=temp)
```

Renders the following:
[image]

`ggplot` as others have note, by itself does not support 3d graphics rendering.

Comment: is it also possible to include a lm() object there?

Comment: @Ben, yes possible. See [this](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business7/uploads/plot/optimized/2X/7/7d0944698d85fb17a9b831f292c9ca0742a03534_2_1210x1000.png) and [this](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business7/uploads/plot/optimized/2X/2/2d10a246842bb183edf80f7f5e948e3a39eb87f0_2_1146x1000.png).

Comment: and how to do that? :)

Comment: @Ben For quick reference, see [this thread](https://community.plot.ly/t/3d-scatter-3d-regression-line/4149) but if that doesn't address what you want, post a question on StackOverflow - happy to help with an answer there

Answer (score 26):

A possible solutions is [gg3D](https://github.com/AckerDWM/gg3D).

gg3D is a package created to extend ggplot2 to produce 3D plots. It does exactly what you are asking for: it adds a third axis to a ggplot. I find it quite good and easy to use and that is what I use for my limited needs.

An example taken from the vignette to produce a basic plot

```
devtools::install_github("AckerDWM/gg3D")

library("gg3D")

## An empty plot with 3 axes
qplot(x=0, y=0, z=0, geom="blank") + 
  theme_void() +
  axes_3D()
```

[image: Empty 3D axes]

```
## Axes can be populated with points using the function stat_3D.

data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Sepal.Width, z=Petal.Length, color=Species)) + 
  theme_void() +
  axes_3D() +
  stat_3D()
```

[image: iris data]

There are other options not involving ggplot. For example the excellent [plot3D](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf) package with its extension plot3Drgl to plot in openGL.

Comment: as of Oct 16, gg3D isn't available for r 3.5.1 :(

Comment: The software has to be installed from GitHub .

devtools::install_github("AckerDWM/gg3D")

Comment: Is gg3d or plot3D compatible with gganimate?

Answer (score 23):

In your question, you refer to the [plotly](https://plotly-r.com/) package and to the [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) package. Both plotly and ggplot2 are great packages: plotly is good at creating dynamic plots that users can interact with, while ggplot2 is good at creating static plots for extreme customization and scientific publication. It is also possible to send ggplot2 output to plotly. Unfortunately, at the time of writing (April 2021), ggplot2 does not natively support 3d plots. However, there are other packages that can be used to produce 3d plots and some ways to get pretty close to ggplot2 quality. Below I review several options. These suggestions are by no means exhaustive.

**[plotly](https://plotly-r.com/)**

See [onlyphantom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51807814)'s answer in this thread.

**[gg3D](https://github.com/AckerDWM/gg3D)**

See [Marco Stamazza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51807232)'s answer in this thread. See also my effort below.

**[scatterplot3d](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/scatterplot3d-3d-graphics-r-software-and-data-visualization)**

See [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779062)'s answer in a related thread.

**[lattice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html)**

See [Backlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723310)'s answer in a related thread.

**[rgl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/rgl.html)**

See this [overview](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/a-complete-guide-to-3d-visualization-device-system-in-r-r-software-and-data-visualization) in the wiki guide.

**[rayshader](https://www.rayshader.com/)**

See this [overview](https://www.rayshader.com/) of this package's wonderful capabilities.

**[trans3d](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/i-made-a-3d-movie/)**

See [data-imaginist](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/i-made-a-3d-movie/) use trans3d to get a cube into ggplot2.

**[ggrgl](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggrgl)**

See this cool and useful [coolbutuseless](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggrgl) introduction.

---

Now let me review some of my efforts with the Lorenz attractor trajectories. While customization remains limited, I've had best results for PDF output with gg3D. I also include a ggrgl example.

**gg3D**

```
# Packages
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2)
library(gg3D)  # remotes::install_github("AckerDWM/gg3D")

# Directory
setwd("~/R/workspace/")

# Parameters
parms <- c(a=10, b=8/3, c=28)

# Initial state 
state <- c(x=0.01, y=0.0, z=0.0)

# Time span
times <- seq(0, 50, by=1/200)

# Lorenz system
lorenz <- function(times, state, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {
    dxdt <- a*(y-x)
    dydt <- x*(c-z)-y
    dzdt <- x*y-b*z
    return(list(c(dxdt, dydt, dzdt)))
  })
}

# Make dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(ode(func=lorenz, y=state, parms=parms, times=times))

# Make plot
make_plot <- function(theta=0, phi=0){
  ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z, colour=time)) +
    axes_3D(theta=theta, phi=phi) +
    stat_3D(theta=theta, phi=phi, geom="path") +
    labs_3D(theta=theta, phi=phi, 
            labs=c("x", "y", "z"), 
            angle=c(0,0,0),
            hjust=c(0,2,2), 
            vjust=c(2,2,-2)) +
    ggtitle("Lorenz butterfly") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}

make_plot()

make_plot(theta=180,phi=0)

# Save plot as PDF
ggsave(last_plot(), filename="lorenz-gg3d.pdf")
```

Pros: Outputs high-quality PDF:

[image]

Cons: Still limited customization. But for my specific needs, currently the best option.

**ggrgl**

```
# Packages
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgl)
  #remotes::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")
library(ggrgl) 
  # remotes::install_github('coolbutuseless/ggrgl', ref='main')
library(devout)
library(devoutrgl) 
  # remotes::install_github('coolbutuseless/devoutrgl', ref='main')
library(webshot2)
  # remotes::install_github("rstudio/webshot2")
library(ggthemes)

# Directory
setwd("~/R/workspace/")

# Parameters
parms <- c(a=10, b=8/3, c=26.48)

# Initial state 
state <- c(x=0.01, y=0.0, z=0.0)

# Time span
times <- seq(0, 100, by=1/500)

# Lorenz system
lorenz <- function(times, state, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {
    dxdt <- a*(y-x)
    dydt <- x*(c-z)-y
    dzdt <- x*y-b*z
    return(list(c(dxdt, dydt, dzdt)))
  })
}

# Make dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(ode(func=lorenz, y=state, parms=parms, times=times))

# Make plot
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z)) +
  geom_path_3d() +
  ggtitle("Lorenz butterfly") -> p

# Render Plot in window
rgldev(fov=30, view_angle=-10, zoom=0.7)
p + theme_ggrgl(16) 

# Save plot as PNG
rgldev(fov=30, view_angle=-10, zoom=0.7,
       file = "~/R/Work/plots/lorenz-attractor/ggrgl/lorenz-ggrgl.png", 
       close_window = TRUE, dpi = 300)
p + theme_ggrgl(16) 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Pros: The plot can be rotated in a way similar to plotly. It is possible to 'theme' a basic plot:

[image]

Cons: The figure is missing a third axis with labels. Cannot output high-quality plots. While I've been able to view and save a low-quality black trajectory in PNG, I could view a colored trajectory like the above, but could not save it, except with a low-quality screenshot:

[image]

Related threads:  [plot-3d-data-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720526/plot-3d-data-in-r), [ploting-3d-graphics-with-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778597/ploting-3d-graphics-with-r).

Comment: Do you know of any R package that can render points moving along trajectories? Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your question, I think you may find what you're looking  for in ``gganimate`` (not sure about 3D, but the package maintainer is super helpful and may have suggestions) : https://gganimate.com/

Comment: @ PatrickT: I will take a look. Thank you!