# How to color the 3D plot based on values of variables in r

Tags: r

I have three coordinates variables and one continuous variable. I would like to get a 3d scatter plot condition on specific values of the continuous variable.

Example of my data is:

```
A = c( 8.3, 7.5, 8.0, 7.1  6.5, 7.4)

x = c(147.2818, 147.2818, 147.2779, 147.2779, 147.2337, 147.1693)

y = c( 147.2818, 147.2818, 147.2779, 147.2779, 147.2337, 147.1693)

z = c( 22, 21, 22, 22, 30, 26)
```

I would like to get the 3d a scatter plot conditioned on the values of A.

For example, if the values of A is between `8` to `8.5`  then the colour is red.

if the values of A is between `7:7.5` then the colour is blue.

finally, if the values of A is between `6:6.5` then the colour is green.

My data contain about 3000 observation. So, I just provide an example of my problem. Any help, please?

### Please note that I used the `ploty` function but as my data is very large, the output was not clear and not helpful.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052188/how-to-plot-3d-scatter-diagram-using-ggplot) one.

Comment: I used it but as my data is very large, so this makes the plot unhelpful and unclear. So, the best way is to consider the level of the values (based on a specific range of values to make it clear to the reader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `ifelse` function,

```
A = c( 8.3, 7.5, 8.0 ,7.1 , 6.5, 7.4)

x = c(147.2818, 147.2818, 147.2779, 147.2779, 147.2337, 147.1693)

y = c( 147.2818, 147.2818, 147.2779, 147.2779, 147.2337, 147.1693)

z = c( 22, 21, 22, 22, 30, 26)

my_color <- ifelse(A<=8.5 & A>8,"red", ifelse(A<=7.5 & A>7,"blue","green"))

plot_ly(x=x, y=y, z=z, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", color=my_color)
```

[image]

Additionally, if you don't want to assign it by using `ifelse`, you can make clusters and assign it to the `plotly` like,

```
n =3 # number of clusters

my_col_cluster <- kmeans(A,n)$cluster

plot_ly(x=x, y=y, z=z, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", color= my_col_cluster)
```

[image]

Comment: This help, however, how about 6.5. For example, if I would like to add another ifelse.

Comment: @Mary 6.5 assigned as green since it is out of the conditions. The mistake in here, 8 also assigned as green since it is not included inside the conditions. If you define the boundaries of the conditions specifically with ending of one is starting of the other, then every number will be assigned correctly.

Comment: Do you mean like this: `ifelse(A > 8,"red", ifelse(A<=7.5 "blue", ifelse (A <= 6.5))? if not, could you please help me with this point?

Comment: @Mary For example , `my_color <- ifelse(A<=8.5 & A>7.5,"red", ifelse(A<=7.5 & A>7,"blue","green"))` . The ends of one  `A>7.5` is the starting of the next `A<=7.5`. But as I suggested, if you don't like it you can just use clusters as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [plot3D](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization) library

```
install.packages("plot3D")
library(plot3D)

## Use ifelse() to create color labels
colVar <- sapply(A,function(a){ifelse(a>=6&a<=6.5,'green',ifelse(a>=7&a<=7.5,'blue','red'))})
colVar <- factor(colVar,levels=c('green','blue','red'))

## Plot using plot3D(). 
## colvar takes integer values for color groups.
## colkey creates the legend
## col sets the color scheme to each group index
scatter3D(x=x,y=y,z=z,
      colvar=as.integer(colVar),
      colkey=list(at=c(1,2,3),side=4),
      col=as.character(levels(colVar)),
      pch=19)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
# If you want a continuous color scale on the z-axis, this is also a possible solution

# Define data
x = c(147.2818, 147.2818, 147.2779, 147.2779, 147.2337, 147.1693)
y = c( 147.2818, 147.2818, 147.2779, 147.2779, 147.2337, 147.1693)
z = c( 22, 21, 22, 22, 30, 26) 

# Make a data frame
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))

# Make z data a factor
data$z <- factor(data$z)

# Determine how many unique observations exist by checking the number of levels, store that number in "length"
length <- length(levels(data$z))

# Create new dummy column of z data
data$dummy <- data$z

# Define the color scale, using viridis here 
color_scale <- colorRampPalette(c("#40478F","#238A8D", "#55C667", "#FDE725"))(n = length)

# Create a vector of color codes that pair with each z value
data$color <- color_scale[data$dummy]

install.packages("scatterplot3d")
install.packages("plotfunctions")
library(scatterplot3d)
library(plotfunctions)

attach(data)
scatterplot3d(x=x,y=y,z=z, #plot data 
              color = data$color, # use color vector
              type = "h",
              pch = 16)

gradientLegend(valRange = c(20,30), # add the legend
               color = c("#40478F","#238A8D", "#55C667", "#FDE725"),
               side = 4,
               pos.num = 1,
               n.seg = 1)
```