Making a 3d plot using ggplot
I have this R code which makes a 3D plot in plotly:
library(plotly)

x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 100)
grid <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
z <- with(grid, sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))/sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + 1) + cos(x*y/4)/2)
z_matrix <- matrix(z, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))

plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z_matrix) %>%
  add_surface(
    contours = list(
      z = list(
        show = TRUE,
        usecolormap = TRUE,
        highlightcolor = "#ff0000",
        project = list(z = TRUE)
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "3D Mathematical Wave Function",
    scene = list(
      camera = list(
        eye = list(x = 1.5, y = 1.5, z = 1.5)
      ),
      xaxis = list(title = "X"),
      yaxis = list(title = "Y"),
      zaxis = list(title = "Z")
    )
  )


I am trying to make this above plot ONLY in ggplot
I have seen other 3d plotting libraries in R (e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html), but is it possible to make this plot exclusively using ggplot?

No, ggplot doesn't do 3d plotting by itself.

For more reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66995534/6851825
