# Plotting multivariate polynomial in R

Tags: r, plot

How can I plot multivariate polynomial such as f(x,y) = 2 + x + x*y^2 + 3*x^3*y^2 in R ?

For univariate polynomial, polynom package does it, but I haven't found multivariate counterpart.

Comment: maybe `emdbook::curve3d` ?

Comment: I guess here is your problem with few solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720526/plotting-3d-data-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(emdbook)
curve3d( 2 + x + x*y^2 + 3*x^3*y^2)
```

[image]