# How to combine multiple 2D R plots into a single 3D plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I am trying to stack multiple 2d plots into a single 3d plot in R.

For example, I want to try and put these plots
[image: these plots] 
into a single 3d image. The z axis would be the biomass density, y axis be the size and the x axis be the time step (and then hopefully I could use a surface plot to join up all the lines). My aim is to try and show the wave travelling through the size over a long period of time instead of showing lots of images.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720526/plotting-3d-data-in-r)? And please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plotting 3D data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720526/plotting-3d-data-in-r)